# Deploying Amber to Heroku

Tags: heroku, amber-framework

**TL;DR** Amber (Granite ORM) is having issues figuring out which driver to use for the Postgres schema.

---

I have an application I recently deployed to Heroku. Following the docs, I could get the default scaffold application deployed to Heroku.

Building the app our further, I added a database to the mix. To deploy this, I realized I had to add the `DATABASE_URL` to Amber somehow. To do this, I ran `amber e` to encrypt the production details, added the DB URL with `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` to the Yaml file, then uploaded the encrypted production database to Heroku.

Loading up the app, I get the following error? Any ideas?

```
ERROR: no driver was registered for the schema "", did you maybe forget to require the database driver? (ArgumentError)
  from ???
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/hash.cr:152:5 in 'database'
  from /tmp/build_7b930c5cce776ceed341783001cb3a8d/lib/db/src/db/query_methods.cr:38:7 in '->'
  from /tmp/build_7b930c5cce776ceed341783001cb3a8d/lib/granite/src/granite/collection.cr:255:3 in 'call'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in 'call'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in 'call'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in 'call'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in 'call'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in 'call'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in '???'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:24:7 in 'call_next'
  from /tmp/build_7b930c5cce776ceed341783001cb3a8d/lib/amber/src/amber/pipes/powered_by_amber.cr:6:9 in '???'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/http/server/request_processor.cr:39:11 in 'process'
  from /tmp/crystal/share/crystal/src/fiber.cr:255:3 in '???'
  from ???
```

I am currently using

- Amber CLI (amberframework.org) - v0.9.0
- Crystal 0.26.1 (2018-08-27)
- LLVM: 6.0.1
- Default target: x86_64-apple-macosx

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried switching `ENV[DATABASE_URL]` to `#{ENV[DATABASE_URL]}` after I tested it with [this script](https://pastebin.com/rSqBnNXJ) — still, the issue persists